# How to save the columns which i added in my datagridview using access database VB.net 2010

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using this code to add a new column:

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Test", "TesT")
```

but after saving and closing the project then I open it again the columns were deleted.

The question is how to save the columns to the access database.

Comment: In wich part of the page life cycle are you adding the code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

If your just going to save the values, than you'd have to call them back up in order to fill the grid.

Sample code to insert into an access db.

```
Dim Cmd as New OLEDb.OleDbCommand
Dim oleConn as New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim strDataBase as String

strDataBase = "C:\Test.mdb"

'2007 connection string will work for 2003-2007 databases - change to 14.0 for 2010 etc
oleConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strDataBase & ";Jet OLEDB"

Cmd.Connection = oleConn
oleConn.Open()
Cmd.CommandText = "Insert into mytable ( Field1, Field2 ) values ( '" & "some Value" & "', '" & "some value" & "' )"
Cmd.ExcuteNonQuery
oleConn.Close()
```

Comment: I'm using 2010
after changing it to 14.0
its not working 
thanks for your help